# PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended for PL/SQL Function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, ora-00933

I am trying to write a `PL/SQL` Function to return Nth highest Salary. I keep getting the Runtime error below. The error is on 'Return result;' line

> PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ORA-06575: Package
>   or function GETNTHHIGHESTSALARY is in an invalid state

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS result NUMBER;

BEGIN

  select Salary into result
  from 
    (select dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as Ranks, ID, Salary
     from Employee) a
     where a.Ranks = N

RETURN result;
END;
```

[snapshot of main code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng71t.png)

Comment: Get in the habit of using `CREATE OR REPLACE` statements when working with functions, procedures, packages, views, etc - e.g. `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` instead of `CREATE FUNCTION`.

Answer (score 2):

You have missing semi-colon `where a.Ranks = N`. It is supposed to be `where a.Ranks = N;`

Comment: Also, the OP should consider using `OR REPLACE` option because the same script will fail as function already exists (so it should be dropped first).